# How to implement AJAX form submission using Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, ajax, flask-admin

I'm trying to use **Flask-Admin** pages on an existing **Flask** backed single page application.
Is there a way to replace the existing page-reload POST method **form** submission while editing/creating a model with an **AJAX** POST mechanism?